# Combining multiple tables using SQL select statements

Tags: sql, database, select

I want to combine the following tables with the logic given below using sql select statement:

**Table: Plant**

| ID | identifier | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cbf2 | 5200 | consistent |
| b3aa | 5201 | consistent |

**Table: Supplier**

| ID | identifier | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3527 | SD501 | consistent |

**Table: Material**

| ID | identifier | code | PC_ID | wxyz_Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b4a1 | B50003 | consistent | a | 1 |
| 97bb | B50004 | consistent | b | 1 |
| e189 | B50005 | consistent | c | 0 |

1. Derived table's *formattedID* column is a combination of *identifier* columns present in the *Plants, Material, Supplier* table.
2. Only rows from the *Material* table will be considered where column *wxyz_Code* is = 1.
3. *wxyz_Code* in *Material* table is renamed as *abcd_Code* in the *DerivedTable* table.
4. *Material_ID*, *Plant_ID*, *Supplier_ID* columns in *DerivedTable* are populated from the *ID* column of *Material*, *Plant*, *Supplier*, respectively.
5. *PC_ID* in *DerivedTable* is filled from Material's *PC_ID* column

**Resulting Table: DerivedTable**

| ID | formattedID | abcd_Code | Material_ID | Supplier_ID | Plant_ID | PC_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Automatically Generated | B50003/5201 | 1 | b4a1 | 'null' | cbf2 | a |
| Automatically Generated | B50003/5200 | 1 | b4a1 | 'null' | b3aa | a |
| Automatically Generated | B50003/5201/SD501 | 1 | b4a1 | 3527 | cbf2 | a |
| Automatically Generated | B50003/5200/SD501 | 1 | b4a1 | 3527 | b3aa | a |
| Automatically Generated | B50004/5201 | 1 | 97bb | 'null' | cbf2 | b |
| Automatically Generated | B50004/5202 | 1 | 97bb | 'null' | b3aa | b |
| Automatically Generated | B50004/5201/SD501 | 1 | 97bb | 3527 | cbf2 | b |
| Automatically Generated | B50004/5200/SD501 | 1 | 97bb | 3527 | b3aa | b |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: **I want to** is not a question. It just informs us that you want us to do the heavy lifting for you.
Where are you stuck? What have you researched? What have you tried? To be clear, we'll help you at stackoverflow but we're not a free do-my-thinking service 
See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this code is for postgreSQL, would apply to many SQL backends with slight change (ie: || with +):

```
select 'Automatically Generated'           as Id,
       m.identifier || '/' || p.identifier as formattedId,
       m.wxyz_code                         as abcd_code,
       m.id                                as Material_Id,
       null                                as Supplier_Id,
       p.Id                                as Plant_id,
       m.pc_id
from Plant p,
     Material m
where m.wxyz_code = 1
union all
select 'Automatically Generated'                                  as Id,
       m.identifier || '/' || p.identifier || '/' || s.Identifier as formattedId,
       m.wxyz_code                                                as abcd_code,
       m.id                                                       as Material_Id,
       s.id                                                       as Supplier_Id,
       p.Id                                                       as Plant_id,
       m.pc_id
from Plant p,
     Supplier s,
     Material m
where m.wxyz_code = 1
order by formattedId;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=90f653734c88a47133b81a5d1e3cbc81)